# Could not autowire field jdbcTemplate - No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

### UPDATE

Adding code in GameDetailImageMapper

```
package spring;

import entities.GameDetailImage;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;


public class GameDetailImageMapper implements RowMapper
{
      public GameDetailImage mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rowNum)  throws SQLException
    {
        GameDetailImage gDetailImage = new GameDetailImage();
        System.out.println("++++++++++++"+rs.toString());
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setGameid( rs.getInt("game_id"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setTitle( rs.getString("title"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setDeveloper( rs.getString("developer"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setPublisher( rs.getString("publisher"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setGenre( rs.getString("genre"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setPlatform( rs.getString("platform"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setGameDescription( rs.getString("game_description"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setDistribution( rs.getString("distribution"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setReleaseDate( rs.getDate("release_date"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setCreateDate( rs.getDate("create_date"));
        gDetailImage.getGameDetail().setScore( rs.getInt("score"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setBanner_link( rs.getString("banner_link"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setBanner_title( rs.getString("banner_title"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setHero_link( rs.getString("hero_link"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setHero_title( rs.getString("hero_title"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setThumbnail_link( rs.getString("thumbnail_link"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setThumbnail_title( rs.getString("thumbnail_title"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setContent_image_link( rs.getString("content_image_link"));
        gDetailImage.getGameImage().setContent_image_title( rs.getString("content_image_title"));
        return gDetailImage;
    }  
}
```

Now that I have pointed my context config to the data.xml file I am getting the below exception. Not sure why this is happening as the query returns the correct data from my database.  I am using a composite object in my mapper (two objects are included in the composite).  Could that be what is causing the issue?

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spring.GameDetailImageMapper.mapRow(GameDetailImageMapper.java:23)
    at spring.GameDetailImageMapper.mapRow(GameDetailImageMapper.java:17)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:400)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
```

I am getting the following exception for my simple spring application. Think because I am not using spring injection correctly for the jdbcTemplate. I am using spring without Maven so no pom.xml. Running on Tomcat.

```
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate spring.GameDetailImageManagement.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

`web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

`data.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

       <bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GameDisplay" />
            <property name="username" value= />
            <property name="password" value= />
            <property name="initialSize" value="2" />
            <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        </bean>

       <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
           <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource"  name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
       </bean>

       <context:annotation-config />


       <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
             <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
       </bean>
       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
       <!--Handle @Autowired-->
<context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

`GameDetailImageController:

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import spring.GameDetailImageManagement;


@Controller
public class GameDetailImageController 
{
    @Autowired
    private GameDetailImageManagement gdm;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
     protected ModelAndView listGameDetailImages
    (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        //ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index", "gameDetailImages", dao.GameDetailImageDAO.getGameDetailImages());
        mv.addObject("gameDetailImages", gdm.getGameDetailImages());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

GameDetailImageManagement

```
    package spring;

    import entities.GameDetailImage;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


    @Component
    public class GameDetailImageManagement 
    {
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Autowired
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
        {
            this.jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
        }


        /*public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) 
        {
            this.jdbcTemplate = template;
        }*/


        public List getGameDetailImages() 
        {
            //List templist;
            //templist = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from GameDetail Inner Join GameImage on GameDetail.game_id = GameImage.game_id Order By GameDetail.create_date", new GameDetailImageMapper());
            //System.out.println("++++===++++"+templist.toString());
            return  this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from GameDetail Inner Join GameImage on GameDetail.game_id = GameImage.game_id Order By GameDetail.create_date", new GameDetailImageMapper());
        }

    }
```

Comment: In your `web.xml` you told the `ContextLoaderListener` that the Spring config file is named `applicationContext.xml`. But in your question above you say that your Spring config is in a file named `data.xml`. There is a mismatch there. Either use the name of the actual file in your `web.xml` or rename the Spring config file.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I am getting a null pointer exception for the jdbcTemplate: Will update above with error.

Comment: The exception happens at line 23 of GameDetailImageMapper.java. We have no idea of what you're doing at that line. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: Added GameDetailImageMapper code for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks pointing the config file to my data.xml was the first step.  The next step was that I wasn't using the mapper correctly.  I added the getters and setters directly to the GameDetailImageMapper without using getGameDetail() and getGameImage().